# burning or collecting transaction fees on PoA

Tags: parity, poa

In Parity PoA, how would you burn or divert all transaction fees to a predefined contract?

Would it be easier in another PoA chain?

Comment: Note sure if this is possible without a code modification in the consensus algorithm.

Comment: That makes sense. Could you be more specific?